# React: Передать состояние дочернего компонента в родительский

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нет, я не хочу и не буду использовать события.
Я пытаюсь создать кастомный input, у которого есть состояние, которым управляет сам элемент, а не его родитель.

Вместо этого

```
export default function Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <Child onClick={handleClick}/>
    <button onClick={e => console.log(value)}>Press me</button>
  );
}
```

мне нужно нечто такое

```
export default function Parent = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  return (
    <Child ref={inputRef}/>
    <button onClick={e => console.log(inputRef.current.value)}>Press me</button>
  );
}
```

Позволяет ли функционал фреймворка передавать состояние потомка таким образом?

Comment: ты пробовал запускать код из вопроса?

Comment: @Grundy полагаю, вопрос в реализации компонента Child

Comment: @MedvedevDev, из текста вопроса этого не видно

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно обернуть дочерний компонент в `React.forwardRef`, в него передать функцию первым аргументом она будет, как и всегда, принимать пропсы, вторым в нее будет передаваться реферальный объект [[подробнее](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef)]

```js
const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <input ref={ref} type="text" />
));
const Parent = () => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Child ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={(e) => console.log(inputRef.current.value)}>Press me</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```